# Retrieve operation not available for Campaign object using ExactTarget SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I simply need to retrieve an array of available campaign names and descriptions using the ExactTarget API, just like you can do for Data Extensions. For example, something like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>Campaign</ObjectType>
              <Properties>ID</Properties>
              <Properties>Name</Properties>
              <Properties>Description</Properties>
           </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, the Retrieve operation does not appear to be available for the Campaign object according to [this list of supported operations](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods/). Is this an oversight or is there a workaround for this? I would consider this to be a pretty essential request and cannot understand why it would not be supported.

Comment: Did you get an error message when you ran this? Docs may not be up to date.  Also,  there are rest routes available, so if this doesn't work I can point you that  direction.

Comment: I use the command `curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction: Retrieve" -d @request.xml https://webservice.test.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx` to execute this SOAP request and receive the response `<OverallStatus>Error: Unable to find a handler for object type: Campaign. Object types are case-sensitive, check spelling.</OverallStatus>`. Interestingly, if I simply change the SOAPAction to `Schedule` this returns a successful response (although I want to retrieve the Campaigns, not schedule them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - slightly confusing here - The `Campaigns` object in the SOAP API refer to what we used to call "Programs".

What you actually need to use here is the REST API.

All of the documentation lives [here](https://code.exacttarget.com/api/hub-campaigns).

The route is `https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns`

You will then be able to retrieve all campaigns using the following:

```
GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns?$page=1&$pageSize=2&$orderBy=Name ASC
```